# Как получать все звуки системы Windows и изменять их?

Tags: c#, windows, аудио

Можно ли получать все звуки системы(прим. звук из фильма или игры) до того как он попадет на колонки? Обработать этот звук программой, и только потом вывести на колонки. Если да, то как это можно реализовать на C#?

Comment: на C# это вряд-ли, нужен прямой контроль драйвера звуковой карты или даже его подмена на преобразователь, который по факту должен сам являться драйвером. Это слишком низкий уровень для .NET

Comment: Посмотрите, например, [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18812224/5045688). Однако, вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4953218/5045688) пишут, что не все звуковые карты поддерживают loopback. Но, вроде, есть и другие [способы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1292499/5045688) (см. там ссылки на Virtual Audio Cable и NAudio).